# Recommendation for book about soil and their food webs

Tags: book-recommendation, soil, food-web

Are there any *de facto* books for studying soil biology; specifically with details in the context of food webs? I am trying to teach myself about the subject and would like a good introductory book, although I will take any recommendations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good resource can be found here:

http://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/global-soil-biodiversity-atlas

If you focus on soil analysis this resource could be helpful:

http://www.geokniga.org/bookfiles/geokniga-handbook-soil-analysis.pdf

I could also recommend the book 
http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642309410
with which I worked extensively. It covers the soil chemistry very well.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoyed reading "Essential Soil Science" by M.R Ashman and G.Puri.

https://g.co/kgs/SCjpSi

Seems to be easy to get online as a pdf as well.